# how to use envoy package in python?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, python-envoy

I have installed package `envoy`. I ran the script but a windows error occured .I commented envoy.run then the full script runs but when I remove the comment, error occurs.

```
 import envoy

 # This data is checked-in to the repository and is a compressed 
 # version of the output from Example 3

 F = 'resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox.json.bz2'

 r = envoy.run("bunzip2 %s" % (F,))
 print r.std_out
 print r.std_err
```

traceback of script:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\sachin\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\sachin\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sachin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\envoy\core.py", line 40, in target
bufsize=0,
File "C:\Users\sachin\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Users\sachin\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You need to provide the full path to "enron.mbox.json.bz2", something like `f = 'C:/path/to/resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox.json.bz2'`

Comment: i also put the full path but same error occured

Comment: You also need to pull the full path to `bunzip2`.

Comment: i am trying to install bunzip2 packege but it doesn't install.does not understand how to instal bunzip2

Comment: You need to first download and install [`bzip2`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bzip2.htm) which will give you the archive utility.

Comment: install bzip2 but same error occure.i think problem in envoy package. i am trying in python shell only enyoy command that is                  import envoy                                                               r=envoy.run('uptime')  then same error occure

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

`F = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox.json.bz2')`